# javascript:void(0) when using %%view_email_url%% for view email link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

We ran into an issue when sending out emails. Previously this function used to work fine and now we are experiencing issues with the %%view_email_url%% function.

Before it succesfully rendered the url as expected. Now it returns a javascript:void(0) the moment I select the data extension for preview/sending. My expectation therefore was an issue in the DA. The DA that worked before however is no longer correctly functioning too with this function. Therefore my expectation is that the issue is located somewhere else.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Surprisingly the AMPscript function used for unsubscribing is working correctly.

Comment: did you try sending the email and then click on the link?

Comment: How are you viewing the email that it is returning this value? Are you selecting a subscriber to mimic so you can view in a send preview or test send?

Comment: Thanks Brad. It turned out that in 1 business unit this was indeed the case. The other was still does not work. I noticed the 'Enable System Generated Links" is unable to be selected in test send.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Gortonington. I am selecting a contact in a data extension for preview.

Comment: You will need to be able to 'Enable System Generated Links' in order to preview this.  Also, I would verify that the subscriber you are using has a status of 'Active'.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington. This was the solution indeed. When using test send this option 'Enable System Generated Links' becomes unavailabe if you do not select a subscriber to send the preview.  This happens in the tab before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling down solution from comments for easier reference to anyone else having this problem:

You will need to check the box for 'Enable System Generated Links' in order to preview all the auto-generated links inside of SFMC emails. In order to access this ability, you will need to select a subscriber in the Preview & Test Send section.

Also, I would verify that the subscriber you are using has a status of 'Active' as if they are unsubscribed, the system will not generate the links and potentially may not even allow the test send.